# Changing Spree from_address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to change Spree 3.0 from_email

I added this line to my spree initialiser, but it does not work:

```
Spree::Store.current.mail_from_address = “x@x.com"
```

Do you know of any reason why not?

I also put it directly in my mailer decorator:

```
Spree::OrderMailer.class_eval do
  def confirm_email_to_store(order, resend = false)
    Spree::Store.current.mail_from_address = "x@x.com"
    @order = order.respond_to?(:id) ? order : Spree::Order.find(order)
    subject = (resend ? "[#{Spree.t(:resend).upcase}] " : '')
    subject += "#{'Will Call' if @order.will_call} #{'Just to See' if @order.just_to_see} ##{@order.number}"
    mail(to: ENV['STORE_EMAIL'], from: from_address, subject: subject)
  end
end
```

This also did not work

Answer (score 1):

Check you might have created multiple stores via checking Spree::Store.all

Also, spree use current store as store which updated last so you have to check that also

Comment: Spree::Store.all - <ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Spree::Store id: 1, name: "Spree Demo Site", url: "demo.spreecommerce.com", meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: nil, seo_title: nil, mail_from_address: "spree@example.com", default_currency: "USD", code: "spree", default: true, created_at: "2016-09-30 17:02:03", updated_at: "2016-09-30 17:02:03">]>

Comment: I was able to configure this through the admin panel, and the configuration persisted

Comment: mail_from_address: "spree@example.com" this is not updated check it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the from email address in the Admin Panel under Configuration -> General settings:

[image: Spree Admin Panel -> Configuration -> General settings]

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work this way:

`Spree::Store.current.update(mail_from_address: ENV["STORE_EMAIL"])`

Looking here http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/ you can see that:

> user.name = "Rob"
>
> This regular assignment is the most common and easiest to use. It is
>   the default write accessor generated by Rails. **The name attribute will
>   be marked as dirty and the change will not be sent to the database
>   yet.**

Of course, spree initializers claims to do save in the databse, but it did not:

> If a preference is set here it will be stored within the cache & database upon initialization.

Finally calling Spree::Store.current will pull from the database, so any unsaved changes will be lost:

```
scope :by_url, lambda { |url| where("url like ?", "%#{url}%") }

def self.current(domain = nil)
  current_store = domain ? Store.by_url(domain).first : nil
  current_store || Store.default
end
```

Fixing this bug in Spree would be prefrable, this is sort of a workaround